# TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes doesnt count videoview's traffic flow

Tags: android, android-videoview, traffic

i'm making a soft to play online video, and i'm trying to add a traffic statistic feature tot the soft. I try to use TrafficStats and getUidRxBytes function. however, it doesnt count the videoview's net traffic. 
Like the following code ,i can see the rx(return by getTotalRxBytes) increase a lot, but the myapprx(return by getUidRxBytes) doesnt change.

```
int uid = VideoViewPlayer.this.getApplicationInfo().uid;
long rx = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes();
long tx = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
long myapprx = TrafficStats.getUidRxBytes(uid);
long myapptx = TrafficStats.getUidTxBytes(uid);
String info = "uid:"+uid+" rx:"+rx+" tx:"+tx+" myrx:"+myapprx+" mytx:"+myapptx;
```

**UPDATE**
Thanks first, your comment gives me important clue. And I'm trying to find the uid responsable for steaming media. I use the following code.However i cannt find the process that comsume the traffic.

```
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> appProcessList = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
        ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo info=null;
        //List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> appProcessList = am.getRunningServices(100);
        //ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo info = null;

        strinfo = "";
        long max =0;
        for(int i=0;i<appProcessList.size();++i)
        {
            info = appProcessList.get(i);
            String key = info.processName+"_" +info.uid;

            if(mNetTraffic.containsKey(key))
            {
                long myrx = TrafficStats.getUidRxBytes(info.uid);
                long lastrx = mNetTraffic.get(key).longValue();
                mNetTraffic.put(key, new Long(myrx));
                if(myrx-lastrx>max && myrx - lastrx>0)
                {
                    max = myrx-lastrx;
                    strinfo = key +":"+max;
                }
            }else
            {
                long myrx = TrafficStats.getUidRxBytes(info.uid);
                mNetTraffic.put(key, new Long(myrx));
            }
        }
        //trying to watch the key and max and find process and uid, sadly cant find it
```

Answer (score 1):

Streaming media should be reported for a different UID, as it is actually streamed and played by an Android internal process and module (OpenCORE or StageFright, depending on Android version).

Comment: Thanks first, your comment gives me important clue. And I'm trying to find the uid responsable for steaming media. and I use the following code.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and managed to find out what UID the process has that streams media: the UID is 1013

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=442557

http://android-dls.com/wiki/index.php?title=Android_UIDs_and_GIDs

Hope it helps :)